# How to import LARGE sql files into mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, apache, mysqlimport

I have a php script that parses XML files and creates a large SQL file that looks something like this:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO table(field1,field2,field3...)
VALUES ("value1","value2",int1...),
("value1","value2",int1)...etc
```

This file adds up to be over 20GB (I've tested on a 2.5GB file but it fails too).

I've tried commands like:

> mysql -u root -p table_name < /var/www/bigfile.sql

this works on smaller files, say around 50MB. but it doesn't work with a larger file.

I tried:

```
mysql> source /var/www/bigfile.sql
```

I also tried mysqlimport but that won't even properly process my file.

I keep getting an error that says

```
ERROR 2006 (HY000): MySQL server has gone away
```

Happens approx. 30 seconds after I start executing.

I set allowed_max_packet to 4GB but when verifying it with SHOW VARIABLES it only shows 1GB.

Is there a way to do this without wasting another 10 hours?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try splitting the file into multiple INSERT queries.

Comment: just imported 2.5gb in about 5 minutes. thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Also take a look at the 'max_allowed_packet = 16M' setting in my.cnf - setting it to something very large like 16M will allow larger single inserts