# Mysql import big sql file

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to import LARGE sql files into mysql table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9337855/how-to-import-large-sql-files-into-mysql-table)

Using php i have exported via odbc some table, which have many many lines, and it's size is about 3GB. Now i need to import that table to my mysql db. But when i try to

> mysql -u root -p DB_development < HUGEdb.sql

after some time it's say : Killed.

Via phpmyadmin interface it's bad to.

My sql file looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO `LINK_LA_TYP` VALUES
 ('1','8917181','1','24','2'),
 ('1','8934610','1','24','1'),
 ('1','9403766','1','30','1'),
 ('1','9422299','1','30','2'),
  many many many so far lines
 ('1','63139389','321','10017','1');
```

Is it any way of importing such table? (source and bigdump doesn't help)

Comment: check your my.cnf configuration, and push limits...

Comment: what limit's you mean? Also when my file has for example ~100mb it good imports, so sql is right... but when 3gb

Comment: This page suggests splitting it up into multipple inserts, or increasing max_allowed_packet: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9337855/how-to-import-large-sql-files-into-mysql-table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are killing the buffer! even through MyAdmin you have to increase the PHP memory. I have had something like that before try this maybe:
Write a php code,while loop the lines and each time clear the variable (each line of record one variable)
then from PHP.ini change your PHP Exec Time out to MAX

Something like this

```
$mysqlCode= "INSERT INTO `LINK_LA_TYP` VALUES ('1','8917181','1','24','2')";
mysql_query("$mysqlCode");
$mysqlCode=null;
```

PS: I STRONGLY recommend not pushing the buffer, you may over load the server. it's better to MAX the execute time and keep refreshing garbage collector, than killing your memory.

Comment: This is not something you can do in one line. A database dump is not always one statement per line, and the `SEPARATOR` can be changed if views or triggers are defined.

Comment: Are there any relations between your values on each line!?

Comment: no, if i understand what you say right

Comment: how many line are there in your dump?!

Comment: don't know) previous has about 60million, that i think has about 80m

Answer (score 2):

I don't know how it's useful for you but maybe help. Just a suggestion;

mydump: https://github.com/qeremy/mydump

You can use "mydump" to export your data, it will export your data by your insert limit (see the _cfg.php:21). After export, unzip your dump files to a dir e.g `local/muydump`, and then you will need some trivial script like this;

```
$files = glob("local/mydump/*.sql");
foreach ($files as $file) {
   $sql = file_get_contents($file);
   $db->query($sql);
}
```

I have accomplish for some db transfer a few gb data with this script (but don't remember how long it taked).

Answer (score 1):

If the length of the statement more then [max_allowed_packet](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet), which is the maximum size of one packet or any generated/intermediate string, then you won't be able to execute this statement. In this case you should split this very-very big statement to many small statement.

Comment: but how than change sql? (will try to read (php) sql and split it)

Comment: how to change to small queries?

Comment: I'm not sure it possible to open such huge file with simple text editor, but I think you can find this program in the internet (google - how to edit big file).

Comment: i mean, could php read/write functions read such files?

Comment: Another variant is to write an application that would create new file with splitted statements.

Comment: Using good text editor (that allows editing huge files) or an application, you can replace '),' with this string '); INSERT INTO LINK_LA_TYP VALUES', it will split your multiple INSERT command to a number of single-record INSERT statements, then just execute this file.