# Streaming files in commandline

Tags: mysql, shell, centos, command-line-arguments

I want to import a very large sql file into my test db server, the file is around 50GB. The problem is if I do `mysql -uuser -p < sqlfile.sql`, it is going to take very looong time due to the file loading time itself.

So I would like to split the files into very small chunks 100MB or so using `split -bytes=100M` but the problem is the split wont be SQL statement aligned (broken insert statements spanning file boundaries).

Now my question is, is there any way to stream multiple files in commandline? something like

`mysql -user -p <1.sql < 2.sql < 3.sql` and so on, if that is possible will I be able to do some shell scripting-fu to use `xargs` and `for` loop to do this for all files in a directory?

EDIT: My attempt to split files is governed by this post, [How to import LARGE sql files into mysql table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9337855/how-to-import-large-sql-files-into-mysql-table). It seems the problem is same as that of mine. Well, the test server is 8 GB, Xeon Quadcore, and I tried the same in another server, with 20 Core 144GB, and it got finished fine with 11hr runtime (shared one with lots of CPU/RAM intensive jobs going on...). The test server, the process is not complete yet complete. So I guess it is the RAM+File loading overhead. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Why does it matter if you do it all at once or not?  It needs to get done eventually, right?

Comment: 11 hours for 50GB files?? Could you please post your `mycnf.conf`. Also there is no issue with importing large files: `nohup mysql -A {credentials + database if needed} < file.sql &`

Comment: try to set larger values for _max_allowed_packet_ and _read_buffer_size_ variables in config file

Comment: @ravnur There is no change in my.cnf, other than changing /var/lib/mysql to /mysqldatadir/

Comment: @vadchen as per my understanding, packet size is for more lengthy statements, right? Will try increasing `read_buffer_size`

Comment: @Aczire, yes, if same value works on another server, than it's good for this particular file. By the way, was this file produced by mysqldump, does it include all necessary commands for optimizing INSERTs? Table locking, keys disabling, etc...

Comment: @Aczire, what engine do you use, do you use replication, redo logs volume?

Comment: @ravnur nothing, just plain standalone MySQL server.

Comment: @vadchan As per the sql head it is "MySQL Administrator dump 1.4", Seems they are using mysql browser or mysql workbench.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is if I do `mysql -uuser -p < sqlfile.sql`, it is going to take very looong time due to the file loading time itself.

There's no "loading time" when you redirect a file like that. MySQL can read the file as fast as it likes; there's no overhead. Splitting the file up is not going to give you any kind of speedup. This is as fast as it gets.

> Now my question is, is there any way to stream multiple files in commandline?

It's going to be slower than leaving the file in one big piece, but if you really want to you can do it:

```
cat 1.sql 2.sql 3.sql | mysql -uuser -p
```

Or alternatively you can run mysql separately for each file:

```
for file in *.sql; do mysql -uuser -p < "$file"; done
```

Comment: Yup, `cat` is what I too first thought. But wont work. Consider `SELECT table_schema "DB Name", sum( data_length + index_length ) / 1024 / 1024 "DB Size in MB" 
FROM inf` in 1.sql and `ormation_schema.TABLES GROUP BY table_schema;` in 2.sql. Te command will fail saying incorrect statement. But I wonder why!